# Display GridLines when copy pasting WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to copy a datagrid in WPF and paste it in a outlook mail. The gridlines seems to be not visible when pasted.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's text only with tabs as column separators.